# Android pay sample app not working

Tags: android, android-pay

Trying to use the Google sample app for Android Pay.
I got the error in logcat:

> "To use this API, you must set the WalletOptions 'brand' field to
>   ANDROID_PAY"

Anyone knows why and can help out?

The link for the sample app is : 
https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart
Thanks

edit: 
attaching the logcat:

```
10-16 10:32:33.564 26114-355/? E/Volley: [4806] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://wallet.google.com/payments/apis/instantbuy/android/v1/getWalletItems
10-16 10:32:33.568 26114-26667/? W/BaseAppContext: Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
10-16 10:32:33.584 21959-21959/? E/OwServiceUtils: Wallet error code: 51
10-16 10:32:33.584 21959-21959/? E/OwServiceUtils: Wallet error detail: To use this API, you must set the WalletOptions 'brand' field to ANDROID_PAY.
```

Comment: Did you follow instruction from https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#set_up_the_sample_and_google_play_services

Comment: Is there something i've missed there?
I've a project in the console with the keytool sha1

Comment: Will test again with a new project and update here.

Comment: New project, both in Google dev console and a clean project in Android studio (Took the sample again) followed the exact tutorial and i get the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here, when i am using WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX there is no issue, but when i am changing it to WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST, the issue appear.

Comment: It was a server side issue, Google fixed it and it is working now.

Comment: I am getting following error for Android Pay in my Production App:
Wallet error code: 51
Wallet error detail: You have not registered to use this API.

Is there anything I am missing? Any help is apprecieated

Answer (score 2):

For Future reference: 
https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/issues/6
The issue was a server issue and was fixed by Google.